# Can read file on shared drive running in Eclipse but cannot when running as a Windows 10 service

Tags: java, windows

I have a mapped drive letter against a remotely shared drive over a VPN:

Z: Mapped to `\\<remote server>\f$\Shared`

When I run my code (Maven Project) under Eclipse Oxygen, The code can read existing files on that share with no problem. (e.g., Z:\MyFiles\ABC.txt)

When I build my code into a one-jar target and deploy that as a Windows Service on Windows 10, the same file cannot be read by the code.

I suspect there needs to be some 'finessing' on the Windows 10 side, but I'm struggling to find what.

Comment: Possibly https://serverfault.com/questions/426288/permanently-mount-network-share-without-the-need-for-log-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with VPN and Windows not mapping it without loading in Windows Explorer first. I've reconfigured the testing rig to avoid this issue.